# Wearable onDataChanged not fired for Wear OS 3 devices

Tags: kotlin, wear-os, wearables

Our wear OS app not receive any onDataChanged events for Wear OS 3 devices such as a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4.
With older version it works as expected. Is there somebody who already makes experience with that new shit? :)

Maybe I have to set in the manifest file a [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) permission, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you reproduce with the samples in https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/DataLayer ? Without your code it's difficult to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with `android:exported="true">` at my Service in the AndroidManifest.
After update my Android Project, Android Studio has commended to set this flag to false.
Now I changed that to true, like the Activities and it works.